# express-handlebars accessing variables declared in the client javascript

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I am learning to use handlebars for templates in my website.

I am using node.js so I have used the express-handlebars module as it seems popular and has a lot of support.

I set up some basic config as so..

```js
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
    defaultLayout: 'layout',
}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

My understanding is that my views in handlebars (ie my content pages) are templates in handlebars and under the hood I think these templates are being compiled on my behalf so that I can concentrate on using them.

Now, I can pass in data to the template from my node express router and then access and render data in the template using the handlebars notation {{ variable }}.

That's great. But....I want to declare variables on the client using javascript, probably as the result of getting some data back from an Ajax call that I want to enter. Unfortunately this never seems to work. I cannot figure out how I can access a local variable in my template. There is surely a way to do it?

the #with block helper looked promising but unfortunately it didn't do what I expected.

Here is a snippet of one of my content pages with a couple of attempts to declare data locally and render its value.

```html
<div>
  <script>let test = {
          text: 'this is my example text'
          };
  </script>

                <div>
                    {{#with test}}
                        {{text}}
                    {{/with}}
                </div>
                
                <div>
                    {{test.text}}
                </div>

</div>
```

I have read a lot of articles and watched a lot of videos and I just cannot find anywhere where somebody uses the 'express-handlebars' module and then renders data defined locally.

I am probably missing something obvious but I have been struggling for a while now.

Does anybody have any idea how I can do this please?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay...it looks like client-side templateing has to be configured separately using webpack. I suppose this makes sense because express handlebars compiles the templates (which just resolves to plain javascript that takes the variables I want to render and wraps in the html needed) and I haven't been able to find any templates on my client through the inspector in the browser. I haven't had chance to try it yet, but this looks promising : http://initialdigital.com/sharing-handlebars-templates-on-both-server-client-in-node-js-express-with-webpack/